# Adjust The Sorting When Adding Cells To UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When I add cells to my UITableView, They are being sorted alphabetically.  When I reload the view, they are being sorted by timeStamp.  I want them to be sorted by timeStamp the whole time, and never alphabetically.

Here is where I add the cell:

```
-(IBAction)createSet
{    
    Set *set = (Set *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Set" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    set.weight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightSelected2];
    set.reps = [NSNumber numberWithInt:repSelected];
    set.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
    [self.exercise addSetsObject:set];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}
```

And here is my fetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Set" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"sets == %@", self.exercise]];
    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: +1 for this nice question, but what if, you reload your table just after you add the cell.

Comment: Thanks, but aren't I already doing that?  At the last line for `createSet` I have `[setsTableView reloadData];`.

Comment: then how you be able to see, that when you add cell these comes in alphabetical order?

Comment: Sorry rptwsthi, I don't understand your last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  reloading your table just after you add the cell.

Comment: Aren't I already doing that?  At the last line for `createSet` I have `[setsTableView reloadData];`.

Comment: [fetchedResultsController release];self.fetchedResultsController = nil;[setsTableView reloadData];
do this.

Comment: If I add that, I get  `*** -[NSFetchedResultsController release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5ef51a0`, because i already have `[fetchedResultsController release];` in `dealloc` because its a class variable.

Comment: If I remove `[fetchedResultsController release];` but keep `;self.fetchedResultsController = nil; [setsTableView reloadData];`, it works fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Adarsh, can you also check out my related question here? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195867/how-to-filter-fetch-data-by-date